# Ставится ли запятая перед авторским тире, если по условиям контекста на его месте должна была быть запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нередко, стремясь к модернизации производства, приобретая новое оборудование — предприятия не уделяют должного внимания тем потерям, которые возникают в результате неоптимальной организации производственных процессов.

Знаю, что тире здесь совершенно лишнее и должно быть заменено запятой, но если оставить так, как сделал автор?..

Comment: По-моему, сама идея добавления чего-либо *противоречит* концепции "*оставить так, как сделал автор*".

Comment: Я собираюсь не добавлять, а заменить. А если окажется, что нужна еще и запятая, - исправить.

Comment: Из вопроса это не понятно.  Тире лишнее и должно быть заменено.  Если тире заменить (на запятую, предположительно), то это нельзя назвать "оставить так". Если оставить так, то это означает, что никаких изменений (замещений или дополнений) не будет.  Или нынче "оставить так" что-то другое означает?

Comment: Я спрашивала о том, нужна ли еще и запятая, если _оставить так, как хотел автор_. Это значит сохранить его волю (оставить тире), но исправить, если то, как он написал, не соответствует правилам.

Comment: А-а...  Тогда нужна запятая. потому что "*приобретая новое оборудование*" - это деепричастный оборот, а их надо отделять запятыми, насколько я помню.

Comment: Я спрашивала, нужна ли запятая перед тире, что тут непонятного?

Comment: Alenka, перечитайте своё последнее предложение, пожалуйста.  Как мы, вне доступа к Вашим мыслям, должны его понимать?

Comment: А зачем вам доступ к моим мыслям? Я спрашивала, отделяется ли запятой деепричастный оборот, если после него стоит еще и интонационное тире (которое здесь совсем не к месту), или она поглощается тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с тире требует некоторой перестройки предложения, с тем чтобы одна его часть была по смыслу противопоставлена другой, например:

Нередко предприятия,   стремясь к модернизации производства, приобретают новое оборудование — и   не уделяют при этом  должного внимания тем потерям, которые возникают в результате неоптимальной организации производственных процессов.

Здесь авторское тире поставлено между однородными сказуемыми.

Comment: Vera, Ваш вариант, конечно, лучше. Но если оставить так, как написал автор, то все же - нужна ли запятая? Потому что такое предложение там не одно. На автора нашло вдохновение ставить везде тире, но оно не везде оправданно, а случаи похожи и приводить их здесь просто глупо. Или Вы настаиваете на том, что тире не интонационное и так писать просто безграмотно?

Comment: В исходном варианте тире оторвало обстоятельство "нередко" от сказуемого (видимо, от этого и напрашивается перефразирование). Если же нужно сохранить тире, не меняя слов, то можно вместо первой запятой поставить ещё одно тире: это превратит в пояснительную вставку оба деепричастных оборота, и восстановится смысловая связь слова "нередко" с тем, что происходит нередко. Возможно, автора такие акценты устроят.

Comment: Интонация исходного предложения не содержит увеличенной паузы,  потому интонационному тире неоткуда взяться. Обособление деепричастных оборотов  с помощью тире в начале предложения сложно объяснить грамматически, даже похожего примера  придумать не получается. Понятно только желание автора противопоставить два процесса, но для этого нужно найти подходящую форму.

Comment: А может быть, автор имел в виду вставку? Нередко —  стремясь к модернизации производства, приобретая новое оборудование — предприятия не уделяют должного внимания тем потерям, которые возникают в результате неоптимальной организации производственных процессов.

Comment: Если бы имел в виду, то упустил бы из виду второе тире, а не первое, которое труднее успеть забыть :)

Answer (score 0):

Если ответить по сути вопроса, то ответ однозначный - нет, тире само по себе является знаком препинания, зачастую заменяющее - как в данном случае! - запятую. 
Что касается неграмотности составленного предложения - неуместности тире и его замена запятым - то на это указала сама автор вопроса.

Можно было бы написать так:

> Нередко, стремясь к модернизации производства **-** приобретая новое оборудование **-** предприятия не уделяют должного внимания тем потерям, которые возникают в результате неоптимальной организации производственных процессов.

Однако в этом случае немного изменился бы смысловой оттенок.

P.S. Уважаемый пользователь Alenka, это тире является всего лишь авторским, и почему Вы его посчитали интонационным я что-то не пойму.

Comment: И что ж, в таком случае запятая не нужна после "производства"?  Тире (или оборот между тире) обеспечивают необходимое отделение частей?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Без запятой здесь никак. Тире можете оставить, коли автор такой зануда, но закрыть деепричастный оборот вы просто обязаны.

Тут же каков принцип. Тире в некоторых случаях может заменять запятую. Но число таких случаев довольно мало и обособление деепричастного оборота в из число не входит. Значит, тире поставлено по каким-то другим мотивам. И коли так, то запятая должна сохраниться. ***Запятая, поставленная по мотивам, отличным от мотивов для тире, не поглощается этим тире.*** Как "Отче наш".

Это вкратце, подробно обсуждать не вижу необходимости, поскольку мотивы для тире здесь совершенно непонятны, авторский знак в худшем понимании этого.

Вариант перестройки предложения я не рассматриваю. Вообще против такой вольности, если автор вопроса не ставит этот вопрос подобным образом, а тут еще и *русским по белому* "оставить, как есть".